# Pandas columns overlap but no suffix specified

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to joins two dataframes:

`df_games`:

```
       jogo_id  rodada_id  time_id     time_nome  adversario_id  ... variacao_num  media_num  jogos_num    status   ano
0       232423          1    293.0  Athletico-PR            267  ...         0.00       0.00          0      Nulo  2019
1       232423          1    293.0  Athletico-PR            267  ...         0.00       0.00          0      Nulo  2019
2       232423          1    293.0  Athletico-PR            267  ...         0.00       0.00          0      Nulo  2019
3       232423          1    293.0  Athletico-PR            267  ...         0.00       0.00          0      Nulo  2019
4       232423          1    293.0  Athletico-PR            267  ...        -2.17       0.40          1      Nulo  2019
...        ...        ...      ...           ...            ...  ...          ...        ...        ...       ...   ...
30825   232429         38    267.0         Vasco            315  ...         0.00       0.70          1      Nulo  2019
30826   232429         38    267.0         Vasco            315  ...        -0.30       2.93         25    Dúvida  2019
30827   232429         38    267.0         Vasco            315  ...         0.00       2.39         17  Suspenso  2019
30828   232429         38    267.0         Vasco            315  ...         0.00       0.00          0      Nulo  2019
30829   232429         38    267.0         Vasco            315  ...         0.00       0.32          8    Dúvida  2019

shape: (30830, 19)
```

and `df_players`:

```
           rank     atleta_nome        posicao
player_id                                     
82730        39  Marcelo Rangel        Goleiro
100651      136         Rodrygo       Atacante
87863       140      Arrascaeta  Meio-Campista

shape: (733, 4)
```

when I try to join them, like so:

```
df_joined = df_games.set_index('player_id').join(players.set_index('player_id'))
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['atleta_nome', 'posicao'],dtype='object')
```

---

But if I try to join the same `df_players` with another df_games_2, like this:

```
     Unnamed: 0                            atletas.nome         atletas.slug      atletas.apelido  ...  PP  GC  DP  round
0             1              Glaybson Yago Souza Lisboa         yago-pikachu         Yago Pikachu  ... NaN NaN NaN      1
1             2            Juan Ramón Cazares Sevillano              cazares              Cazares  ... NaN NaN NaN      1
2             3  Alessandro Vinícius Gonçalves da Silva  alessandro-vinicius  Alessandro Vinícius  ... NaN NaN NaN      1
3             4                    Diego Alves Carreira          diego-alves          Diego Alves  ... NaN NaN NaN      1
4             5             Réver Humberto Alves Araújo                rever                Réver  ... NaN NaN NaN      1
..          ...                                     ...                  ...                  ...  ...  ..  ..  ..    ...
843         844                  Lucas Piton Crivellaro          lucas-piton          Lucas Piton  ... NaN NaN NaN     38
844         845         Alan Carlos de Paula Dias Filho                 alan                 Alan  ... NaN NaN NaN     38
845         846                  Roni Medeiros de Moura                 roni                 Roni  ... NaN NaN NaN     38
846         847               Alexander Silva de Lucena            alexander            Alexander  ... NaN NaN NaN     38
847         848          Riquelme Carvalho Araújo Viana             riquelme             Riquelme  ... NaN NaN NaN     38

[30581 rows x 34 columns]
```

the join works.

Why can I join by `player_id` on the first case and not on the second case?

How do I fix this? I need to join `df_games`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `merge` instead of `join`, or you can pass suffixes in your call:

```
df_joined = df_games.set_index('player_id').join(players.set_index('player_id'), lsuffix="_games", rsuffix="_players")
```